# Vaadin front-end for social network?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin4spring

From the information I've gathered, Vaadin seems best suited for business related applications.

I'm just wondering if anyone with experience could tell me if it would be possible to create Facebook 2.0 with Vaadin? It seems like a really good front-end for such a thing and I see many possibilities for amazing user experiences.

(That's not what I'm aiming to do, just trying to make the question more concrete)

Note that I'm a beginner and currently developing using Thymeleaf as my template engine.

Comment: Please take a quick look at [What types of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This is an extremely broad, open ended question that is asking for opinion and speculation.

Comment: with Vaadin if you want you can develop even google.com in just 5 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend Vaadin as a technology for realizing a social network. Vaadin is a server-side UI framework that stores the UI state in the session. With thousands of concurrently active users you have a massive memory consumption on the server. I would rather use a fat-client approach with client-side technologies such as angularJS.

Comment: This answer is good but I could still close that question instead of posting the response.